# Is it possible to pass type parameters to a generic parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Is something like the following possible:

```js
interface Foo<X> {
    bar: X<string, number>
}
```

I am assuming it is not possible, but Typescript's type system has suprised me before.

Comment: Not possible.. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Comment: I would suggest you to describe your use case; perhaps there's another way to satisfy it.

Answer (score -1):

Just omit `X` on the interface level and define it on the property:

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: X<string, number>
}
```

Comment: the `X` itself is type parameter 

Comment: For the use-case presented in the question, this solves the problem.